# image processing using vhdl /MATLAB

Tags: fpga, vhdl

how i can get acces to  binary file  content pixel of image from ENVI logi (100*100) pixel coded each pixel in 16 bits in vhdl or in matlab , when i get acces i want to modify the file?
thanks

Comment: Read in the bit stream with fread and parse it.

Comment: @ laptop2d can you explain more , i know the  instructions how  to read and write

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, use the `imread()` function (and friends).

In VHDL, you need a `file` object. Of course, this only works in simulation.

Seriously, have you read any of the available documentation?

Comment: yes of course i read the documentation in the both MATLAB and VHDL . I know how i can read and write in VHDL txt format but in binary file  its little difficult,i want some idea how i can get acces to binary file like creat a 2D array to store or the size of file ..., thankyou for your time